# Location Information in Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need to find out how does Stanford NER tool recognizes the location information from the given text.
Is it based on the structure of sentence only or does it uses any location database on the top of structure of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The present model doesn't explicitly use a gazetteer of location info, but since it is trained on a substantial amount of hand-labeled text, in practice it does "know" a lot of common place names, as well as using the sentence context.